# How to kill Mysql Pending threads?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cpu-usage, mariadb-10.4

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with PHP application connected to MySQL database.
Often, using Mytop, I detect some stuck MySQL threads:

```
   Id      User         Host/IP         DB       Time     Cmd    State 
   --      ----         -------         --       ----     ---    ----- 
1725310  ms_db_use  184.126.65.142   app_pro     19716   Sleep
2370165  ms_db_use  localhost:58210  app_pro      1385   Query   Copying
```

As you can see above, some threads are stucked for 19k seconds. This is putting overload on my cpu sometimes so my question is:

Is there any way to automate this to automatically kill the thread if it is not resolved in X Amount of seconds? The purpose of this is to remove overload from CPU.

---

According to this it is PHP application on my server, just I am not sure how to troubleshoot that part:

> PID USER PRI VIRT RES SHR S CPU MEM% COMMAND  124 megax 20 335M 19254
> 21212 S 100.00% 0.0  php-fpm: pool www 125 megax 20 335M 19254 21212 S
> 100.00% 0.0 php-fpm: pool www 126 megax 20 335M 19254 21212 S 100.00% 0.0 php-fpm: pool www 127 megax 20 335M 19254 21212 S 100.00% 0.0 php-fpm: pool www

Comment: Cmd `Sleep` it appears not to be doing anything anyway, it's probably waiting for a call so is not using CPU much.

Comment: I don't see anything there to worry about especially if you are not seeing high CPU usage.

Comment: actually i see high cpu usage whenever i am having mysql thread in idle from localhost

Comment: Please post your complete htop or top first page of output so we can see what you are observing. KILLING things is not a generally recommended procedure.  Much damage can be done to your system.